Automatically select current day on page load in calendar component
I am building a homepage in React where a calendar component displays matches based on the selected date. I want the calendar to automatically highlight and filter matches for the current day when the page loads, without requiring any user interaction. However, despite my setup, the current day only gets selected after manually clicking on it. Here's a breakdown of my component and what I've tried so far:
// src/pages/HomePage.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import LeagueList from '../components/LeagueList';
import NewsList from '../components/NewsList';
import { useLoaderData } from "react-router-dom";
import { weekDaysArray } from '../lib/calendar';
import { fetchAllLeagues, fetchAllGames, fetchAllNews } from '../lib/gamesFetching';

export async function loader() {
  const [leagues, gamesByLeague, news] = await Promise.all([
    fetchAllLeagues(),
    fetchAllGames(),
    fetchAllNews()
  ]);

  const integratedLeagues = leagues.map((league) => ({
    ...league,
    matches: gamesByLeague[league.id] || []
  }));

  return {
    leagues: integratedLeagues,
    news
  };
}

function filterMatchesByDate(leagues, targetDate) {
  return leagues.map(league => {
      const filteredMatches = league.matches.filter(match => match.date === targetDate);
      
      return {
          ...league,
          matches: filteredMatches
      };
  }).filter(league => league.matches.length > 0);
}

const HomePage = () => {
  const today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]; // Format YYYY-MM-DD
  const { leagues: initialLeagues, news } = useLoaderData();

  const [selectedDay, setSelectedDay] = useState(today)
  const [filteredLeagues, setFilteredLeagues] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const leaguesForSelectedDay = filterMatchesByDate(initialLeagues, selectedDay);
    setFilteredLeagues(leaguesForSelectedDay);
  }, [selectedDay, initialLeagues]);

  const calendarHandler = (date) => {
    setSelectedDay(date);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto max-w-6xl my-10">
      <section className="mb-6 bg-white p-4 rounded-md grid grid-cols-4 gap-4">
        <NewsList news={news} />
      </section>

      <section className="mb-6 bg-white p-4 rounded-md">
        <div className="flex items-center justify-between mb-6">
          <h2 className="text-xl">Meciuri:</h2>
          <div className="flex items-center gap-1 text-sm">
            {weekDaysArray.map(day => (
              <div className={`cursor-pointer py-1 px-2 rounded-md text-center hover:bg-gray-200 ${day.fullDate === selectedDay ? "bg-emerald-200 shadow-md hover:bg-emerald-200" : ""}`}
                key={day.date}
                onClick={() => calendarHandler(day.fullDate)}
              >
                <div>{day.name}</div>
                <div className={`text-xs ${day.fullDate === selectedDay ? "text-emerald-700" : "text-gray-400"}`}>{day.date}</div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
        <LeagueList leagues={filteredLeagues} />
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HomePage;

This is my calendar.js file:
const getWeekDays = () => {
    const days = ['Dum', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mie', 'Joi', 'Vin', 'Sâm'];
    const today = new Date(); // Obține data curentă
    const weekDays = []; // Array pentru a stoca zilele
    const todayDateString = `${today.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0')}-${(today.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0')}`; // Format dd-mm pentru ziua curentă

    for (let i = -3; i <= 3; i++) {
        const day = new Date(today); // Creează o copie a zilei curente
        day.setDate(today.getDate() + i); // Setează data pentru ziua dorită

        const dayName = days[day.getDay()];
        const dateString = `${day.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0')}-${(day.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0')}`; // Format dd-mm
        weekDays.push({ name: dayName, date: dateString, fullDate: day, isToday: dateString === todayDateString }); // Adaugă obiectul cu numele zilei și data
    }

    return weekDays;
}

const today = () => {
    const day = new Date();

    // Obține numele zilei din array-ul de zile
    return `${day.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0')}-${(day.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0')}`; // Format dd-mm
}

export const weekDaysArray = getWeekDays();
export const currentDay = today();
console.log(weekDaysArray);

It works when I click on the calendar item, but the current day in calendar does not start highlighted.
I have tried:

Initialized selectedDay with today's date using useState(today).
Used useEffect to update filteredLeagues whenever selectedDay or initialLeagues change.
Verified that initialLeagues contains data before running the filter function.
Console-logged initialLeagues to confirm that data is loaded.


What is day.fullDate? I'd guess some kind of (Date?) object, which is equality-compared by identity/reference, not value.

"Hi! day.fullDate is actually a string in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD', which we’re using for comparison. It’s extracted from a Date object and formatted for easy string equality checks. Since day.fullDate is not a Date object, it compares by value rather than by reference. Hope that clarifies!"

That's not what the code you just posted says...

day.fullDate appears to be a javascript date object, unlike today which is a string in yyyy-mm-dd format.  Consider converting day.fullDate to the same data type and format as today.

Thanks everyone for your help. I solved it. I had some errors. Final structure:
HomePage.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import LeagueList from '../components/LeagueList';
import NewsList from '../components/NewsList';
import { useLoaderData } from "react-router-dom";
import { weekDaysArray } from '../lib/calendar';
import { fetchAllLeagues, fetchAllGames, fetchAllNews } from '../lib/gamesFetching';

export async function loader() {
  const [leagues, gamesByLeague, news] = await Promise.all([
    fetchAllLeagues(),
    fetchAllGames(),
    fetchAllNews()
  ]);

  const integratedLeagues = leagues.map((league) => ({
    ...league,
    matches: gamesByLeague[league.id] || []
  }));

  return {
    leagues: integratedLeagues,
    news
  };
}

function filterMatchesByDate(leagues, targetDate) {
  return leagues.map(league => {
      const filteredMatches = league.matches.filter(match => match.date === targetDate);
      return {
          ...league,
          matches: filteredMatches
      };
  }).filter(league => league.matches.length > 0);
}


const HomePage = () => {
  const today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]; // Format YYYY-MM-DD

  const { leagues: initialLeagues, news } = useLoaderData();

  const [selectedDay, setSelectedDay] = useState(today);
  const [filteredLeagues, setFilteredLeagues] = useState(() => filterMatchesByDate(initialLeagues, today));

  useEffect(() => {
    const leaguesForSelectedDay = filterMatchesByDate(initialLeagues, selectedDay);
    setFilteredLeagues(leaguesForSelectedDay);
  }, [selectedDay]);

  const calendarHandler = (date) => {
    setSelectedDay(date);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto max-w-6xl my-10">
      <section className="mb-6 bg-white p-4 rounded-md grid grid-cols-4 gap-4">
        <NewsList news={news} />
      </section>

      <section className="mb-6 bg-white p-4 rounded-md">
        <div className="flex items-center justify-between mb-6">
          <h2 className="text-xl">Meciuri:</h2>
          <div className="flex items-center gap-1 text-sm">
            {weekDaysArray.map(day => {
              const isSelected = day.fullDate === selectedDay;
              return (
                <div
                  className={`cursor-pointer py-1 px-2 rounded-md text-center hover:bg-gray-200 ${isSelected ? "bg-emerald-200 shadow-md hover:bg-emerald-200" : ""}`}
                  key={day.fullDate}
                  onClick={() => calendarHandler(day.fullDate)}
                >
                  <div>{day.name}</div>
                  <div className={`text-xs ${isSelected ? "text-emerald-700" : "text-gray-400"}`}>{day.date}</div>
                </div>
                
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
        <LeagueList leagues={filteredLeagues} />
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HomePage;

and Calendar.js
const getWeekDays = () => {
    const days = ['Dum', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mie', 'Joi', 'Vin', 'Sâm'];
    const today = new Date(); 
    const weekDays = []; 
    const todayDateString = `${today.getFullYear()}-${(today.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0')}-${today.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0')}`; 

    for (let i = -3; i <= 3; i++) {
        const day = new Date(today);
        day.setDate(today.getDate() + i);

        const dayName = days[day.getDay()];
        const dateString = `${day.getFullYear()}-${(day.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0')}-${day.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0')}`; 
        weekDays.push({ name: dayName, date: `${day.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0')}-${(day.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0')}`, fullDate: dateString, isToday: dateString === todayDateString }); 
    }

    return weekDays;
};

const today = () => {
    const day = new Date();

    return `${day.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0')}-${(day.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0')}`; // Format dd-mm
}

export const weekDaysArray = getWeekDays();
export const currentDay = today();
console.log(weekDaysArray);

Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. It's my first post.
